# How do I access the output of a completed gcloud ml speech-to-text operation in Mac OS Terminal (or via Gcloud web UI?)

Tags: gcloud, speech-to-text

I successfully installed Gcloud for Mac OS (Terminal use). I figured out how to run the proper command to transcribe a 60-min 2-person interview MP3 file from speech to text. The job finished successfully ("Describe" command shows 100% done). I cannot find the text transcription file/output in the Gcloud website, or in a local file on my Mac, or via the terminal.

Tried various flags on the command, including --user-out-enabled. No change. Using "describe" for each of the (3) attempts, it just says the job successfully finished.

The final attempt I ran:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running  'gs://transcription-conversions/myfile.mp3' --async --language-code="en-US" --encoding="LINEAR16" --sample-rate=16000 --user-output-enabled
```

Then I ran this to see if the job finished properly. It did, I think:

```
gcloud ml speech operations describe  

{
  "done": true,
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata",
    "lastUpdateTime": "2019-04-23T22:48:10.075437Z",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2019-04-23T22:45:20.132178Z"
  },
  "name": "12345"
}
```

However, I am not sure where/how to get the text output of the 12345 job/name shown above. Where is the text transcript? How do I access it?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue and for me only happens with mp3 format, could you convert your file to flac format [1](https://superuser.com/questions/339023/convert-audio-file-to-flac-with-ffmpeg) and run your command without format arguments?

Here are an example:

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp3 -c:a flac myfile.flac

gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running 'gs://transcription-conversions/myfile.flac' --language-code='en-US'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Currently the MP3 format is not [supported](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings) and you should follow our [Feature Request](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123214264).

If converting to a support encoding is not ideal, you can use the [API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/) to attempt MP3 translations, however, there is no guarantee of the [quality](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#lossy_compression). This is why you are not receiving any output as currently only the API will accept MP3 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

For google cloud speech-to-text:

The documentation recommends .wav files at 16000Hz

`16bit 16000Hz mono .wav` has worked for me.

I take my original recording (or rip from video) and do a pass with some EQ and voice limiting effects (with freeware Audacty, or Adobe Audition) then `save as` in the format above — then upload that to gc storage, then run `ml speech` on it.

To access the transcription (output) you write it to file with the `>` operator at the end of the command, like this `> my-file.txt` … *(see below)*

BTW,you  can also use the `alpha` version of `ml speech`. It accepts a few more flags that help the AI with transcription. My command looks like this:

`gcloud alpha ml speech recognize-long-running gs://my-bucket/my-audio-16bit-16k.wav --language-code=en-US --enable-automatic-punctuation --sample-rate=16000 --max-alternatives=1 --interaction-type=dictation --original-media-type=video --recording-device-type=pc --naics-code=541613 > my-transcript.txt`

… you see I write the output into a `.txt`

Here is the documentation on the alpha: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/ml/speech/recognize-long-running